# Meanings of project into null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have a vector $V$. I project $V$ to its left null space by multiplying it with matrix $A$. $V$ represents $(x, y)$ coordinates of a point in $2D$ space. What would be physical interpretation of this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your notation, the left null space of a vector $V\in \mathbb{R}$ is the matrix $A$ such that $AV = 0$. On the $2d$ plane $A$ represents the vector orthogonal to $V$ (but if $V$ is a zero vector $A$ is formed by the basis on $2d$ plane).

So, projecting $V$ to its left null space will result in zero, because $V$ is orthodonal to it by definition.

Comment: Yes, it is zero. But what would be the physical interpretation? like now my  coordinates denote the $(0,0)$?

Comment: @IsamAbdullah, yes, exactly. Projection results in receiving zero vector.